# What is the proper way of getting the newest mscomctl.ocx?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vb6

I have to maintain an old Visual Studio 6 VB6 project.

The version of Visual Studio 6 is "Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 (SP6) for 32-Bit Windows Development, Version 9782".

The person who developed the project isn't with us anymore, I have no information concerning this project.

One question with this project is "Common Controls".

According to MS there are 2 DLLS (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896559/EN-US):

```
Comctl32.ocx contains Windows Common Controls 5.0 and was included with Microsoft Visual
Studio 5.0. Mscomctl.ocx contains Windows Common Controls 6.0 and was included 
with Visual Studio 6.0
```

When - in Visual Studio - I go to Project - Components - I find in Controls:

"Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)" (MSCOMCTL.OCX)

On one of our production computers (where this standard vb6 runs) there is no mscomctl.ocx, so I wanted to find a proper way to install this. At the microsoft website I found a url:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259403

I was very surprised to NOT find mscomctl.ocx in the files list of "Vcredist.exe".

What is the proper way of getting the newest mscomctl.ocx for Windows 7? Is there a microsoft url where I can type in the name of the file?

After googling for some time I found out that a MS update (MS12-060) from August 14th, 2012 had a new version 6.1.98.34 of mscomctl.ocx. But many people complained about this version and recommended to stay with version 6.1.98.33. Did MS fix this and has now a version 6.1.98.35?

And a last question. What is the difference between mscomctl.ocx and mscomctl.dll?

Thanks alot in advance

Wolfgang

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the proper source for Windows Common Controls 6.0 component (MSCOMCTL.OCX)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226319/whats-the-proper-source-for-windows-common-controls-6-0-component-mscomctl-ocx)

Comment: What is your installer?

Comment: You should get the latest MSCOMCTL.OCX from [cumulative update rollup for the Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Runtime Extended Files](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/957924). That's why Microsoft released it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your last question first. .ocx files are controls, .dll files are libraries.  They both have similar function, in that they are dynamically linked into an .exe file at runtime, but controls have a visual element and libraries don't (usually, and generally shouldn't).

The "manual" way to install mscomctl.ocx on your host machine is to copy it to a folder (look for other visual studio ocx files, and put it in there), and then run Regsvr32.exe to register it.  To automate the installation of the ocx file, you'll need to include it in the cab file that you use for installation.