# Reference library in word - Common Controls

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am distributing a normal.dotm file on my work network. I recently implemented a month picker view in my form but two of the user does not have Windows Common Controls library on their PC. So can I somehow bindle the libraries I use in the normal.dotm file or use create object method or something when initializing the month picker?

Has someone else had the same problems?

Comment: See if the information in this discussion helps you further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226319/whats-the-proper-source-for-windows-common-controls-6-0-component-mscomctl-ocx FWIW, doing a Google search on Windows Common Controls indicates they're installed with Windows and/or Internet Explorer so you should check how the users' configurations differ from the other environments.

Comment: Great, I just figured out that someone got IE11 and others IE9, I manage to remove the library and it now works for all users. Thanks